# Difference between Context-sensitive grammar and Context-free grammar

Tags: algorithm, context-free-grammar, context-sensitive-grammar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Context-sensitive grammar and Context-free grammar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8236422/context-sensitive-grammar-and-context-free-grammar)

In my textbook, here is the explain of these two terms :

Context Sensitive Grammar:

> grammar can have productions of the form w1 → w2, where w1 = lAr and
>   w2 = lwr, where A is a nonterminal symbol, l and r are strings of zero
>   or more terminal or nonterminal symbols, and w is a nonempty string of
>   terminal or nonterminal symbols. It can also have the production S → λ
>   as long as S does not appear on the right-hand side of any other
>   production.

Context Free Grammar:

> grammar can have productions only of the form w1 → w2, where w1 is a
>   single symbol that is not a terminal symbol. A type 3 grammar can have
>   productions only of the form w1 → w2 with w1 = A and either w2 = aB or
>   w2 = a, where A and B are nonterminal symbols and a is a terminal
>   symbol, or with w1 = S and w2 = λ.

In my textbook, the author said :  CSG is a special case of CFG. But, I don't get this point. because in CSG, lAr -> lwr. l and r  can be **strings of zero** or more terminal or nonterminal. So, when it is a string of zero (means : length = 0). we can write lAr as A. So, CSG will be CFG. So, CSG **is** CFG

Does something I have understand wrong ? Please correct it for me.

Thanks :)

Comment: I would say it the other way -- CFG is a special case of CSG.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8250104/759019) might help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The textbook is in error. As you say, a CFG is a special case of a CSG.

CSGs can express strictly more languages than CFGs can.

Comment: Can you tell me more, please. Because, I see that CSG has some condition for context, but CFG. so, I think, CSG should be special case of CFG

Comment: Can you give me some examples, and tell me difference, thanks :)

Comment: A CFG is equivalent to a CSG where every rule has an empty string for both left and right context. Therefore, every CFG can be written as a CSG, but not every CSG can be written as a CFG. So, by definition, a CFG is a special case of a CSG.